# $A$ is a maximally abelian von Neumann algebra iff $A=A'$

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let  $A$ be an abelian von Neumann algebra (say,acting on the Hilbert space $H$).
I want to show that $A$ is a maximally abelian von Neumann algebra on $H$ if and only if $A=A'$.

I managed to prove that if $A=A'$, then $A$ is maximally abelian. I'm stuck on showing the converse though.

So assume $A$ is maximally abelian. Then $A \subseteq A'$. Since $A'$ is a VNA, one possible approach is showing that $A'$ is again abelian and then the maximality will imply $A=A'$. But I'm not sure this is even true. If $x \in A'$, then maybe the VNA generated by the commuting elements $A \cup \{x\}$ is abelian (?) so then we will get $x \in A$ once again by maximality. But I'm not sure why either one of thse claims should be true.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $(A\cup\{x\})''$ is abelian if $x\in A'$ and $A$ is abelian. For simplicity, you can assume without loss of generality that $x^*=x$. Then you have
$$
(A\cup\{x\})''=\{p(a,x):\ a\in A,\ p\in\mathbb C[s,t]\}'',
$$
and the latter algebra is clearly abelian since $xa=ax$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: Are you implicitely assuming that $id_H \in A$?

Comment: If it isn't, then $A$ is not maximal abelian.

Comment: Why? I guess because the VNA generated by $A \cup \{id_H\}$ is abelian, but why is the latter statement true?

Comment: The elements of that algebra are of the form $a+\lambda 1$, for $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: I can see that is true if I can show that $A+ \Bbb{C}id_H$ is strongly closed. Is there a quick way to see this is the case?

Comment: Is it maybe more generally true that the inner direct sum of von Neumann algebras is again a von Neumann algebra?

Comment: The algebra $A+\mathbb C 1$ is a von Neumann algebra. But you don't need it here. You can just say that $A+\mathbb C1$ is an abelian algebra that contains $A$ properly. It's closure will also be abelian. All you need to show is that the closure of an abelian algebra is abelian.

Comment: I am interested seeing in why $A+ \Bbb{C}1$ is a VNA. We have $(A + \Bbb{C}id_H)' = A'$. Maybe an application of the double commutant theorem can help

Comment: What you do is, if $p$ is the unit of $A$, note that $A+\mathbb C1=A+\mathbb C(1-p)$. Now you have a direct sum, so $(A+\mathbb C(1-p))'=A'+(1-p)B(H)(1-p)$, and $(A+\mathbb C(1-p))''=A''+\mathbb C(1-p)$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: No problem :) $ $

Comment: Follow up if you have time/are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822775/strong-closure-of-an-abelian-algebra-is-abelian Thanks!