# Strong closure of an abelian $*$-algebra is abelian.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A \subseteq B(H)$ be a $*$-subalgebra of the bounded operators on the Hilbert space $H$. Let $B$ be the SOT-closure of $A$. Is $B$ again abelian?

Let $u,v \in B$. We can find nets $(u_\lambda), (v_\lambda)$ in $A$ with $u_\lambda \to u$ and $v_\lambda \to v$ in the strong topology. The obvious guess would be that $u_\lambda v_\lambda \to uv$ but in general this is not true since the multiplication map is not strongly continuous, so we will need to make another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you can do it in two steps. For any $a\in A$, $ua=\lim u_\lambda a=\lim au_\lambda=a\lim u_\lambda=au$. Now $uv=\lim uv_\lambda=\lim v_\lambda = vu$.

Comment: Of course... How couldn't I see this!

Comment: If it's any consolation, it has happened to me several times that I don't know how to do an exercise, and when I google it, the first result is my own answer in Math SE.

Comment: At least you found it yourself :D

Answer (score 2):

In case $A$ is unital there is another approach:  von Neumann's double commutant Theorem says that the strong closure of $A$
coincides with $A''$, where the *commutant* $B'$ of a subset $B\subseteq B(H)$ is defined by
$$
  B'=\{T\in B(H): TS=ST,  \text{ for all } S\in B\}.
  $$

The fact that $A$ is abelian translates into $A\subseteq A'$ and since the operation of taking the commutant is clearly
inclusion-reversing, we have that $A''\subseteq A'$.  Applying this once more we get $A''\subseteq A'''$ which
precisely says that $A''$ (a.k.a. the strong closure of $A$),  is commutative.

Comment: The Double Commutant Theorem requires $A$ to be non-degenerate, which is not an assumption here. It's not a big hurdle, but you need to write a bit more to say that the closure of $A$ is a subset of $A''$. For the non-initiated, your answer is also missing mention of the fact that $A'''=A'$

Comment: Hi @MartinArgerami, to avoid getting distracted by the nitty-gritty of the double commutant Theorem I assumed that $A$ is unital but, yes, you are right to say that the same proof also holds for the more general case of a non-degenerate algebra.  In fact it also applies in full generality as long as you pay your respects to the essential space for the algebra.  Regarding the fact that $A'''=A'$, you are again correct that this holds true, but I don't think it is relevant for the proof that $A''$ is commutative.